# Bind one route to different controllers depending on user roles

Tags: symfony

In my Symfony 2 app I have 3 different user roles that can have access to a backend administration part :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_STAFF:     ROLE_USER
    ROLE_MODERATOR: ROLE_STAFF
    ROLE_ADMIN:     ROLE_MODERATOR
```

For a route like `http://example.org/admin/post/`, I'd like my app to display different informations depending on the user role, which means **3 controllers** binding to an **only route**.

What's the best way to handle this ?

I was thinking about some solutions but none seems to be good for me :

1. One controller, and in each action I just test user role :

   ```
   <?php

   /**
    * @Route("/admin/post")
    */
   class PostController extends Controller
   {
       /**
        * Lists all post entities.
        *
        * @Route("/", name="post_index")
        * @Template()
        * @Secure(roles="ROLE_STAFF")
        */
       public function indexAction()
       {
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

           if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_STAFF')) {
               // Do ROLE_STAFF related stuff
           } else if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_MODERATOR')) {
               // Do ROLE_MODERATOR related stuff
           } else if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
               // Do ROLE_ADMIN related stuff
           }

           return array('posts' => $posts);
       }
   }
   ```

   Even if that does the job, IMO obviously that's not a good design.
2. One BackendController that dispatch to 3 different controllers :

   ```
   <?php

   /**
    * @Route("/admin/post")
    */
   class PostBackendController extends Controller
   {
       /**
        * Lists all post entities.
        *
        * @Route("", name="admin_post_index")
        * @Template("AcmeBlogBundle:PostAdmin:index.html.twig")
        * @Secure(roles="ROLE_STAFF")
        */
       public function indexAction()
       {
           if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_STAFF')) {
               $response = $this->forward('AcmeBlogBundle:PostStaff:index');
           } else if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_MODERATOR')) {
               $response = $this->forward('AcmeBlogBundle:PostModerator:index');
           } else if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
               $response = $this->forward('AcmeBlogBundle:PostAdmin:index');
           }

           return $response;
       }
   }
   ```

   Same as number one.
3. I tried to make controllers extends each others :

   ```
   <?php

   /**
    * @Route("/admin/post")
    */
   class PostStaffController extends Controller
   {
       /**
        * Lists all post entities.
        *
        * @Route("/", name="post_index")
        * @Template()
        * @Secure(roles="ROLE_STAFF")
        */
       public function indexAction()
       {
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

           // Do ROLE_STAFF related stuff

           return array('posts' => $posts);
       }
   }

   <?php

   /**
    * @Route("/admin/post")
    */
   class PostModeratorController extends PostStaffController
   {
       /**
        * Lists all post entities.
        *
        * @Route("/", name="post_index")
        * @Template()
        * @Secure(roles="ROLE_MODERATOR")
        */
       public function indexAction()
       {
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

           // As PostModeratorController extends PostStaffController,
           // I can either use parent action or redefine it here

           return array('posts' => $posts);
       }
   }

   <?php

   /**
    * @Route("/admin/post")
    */
   class PostAdminController extends PostModeratorController
   {
       /**
        * Lists all post entities.
        *
        * @Route("/", name="post_index")
        * @Template()
        * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
        */
       public function indexAction()
       {
           $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

           // Same applies here

           return array('posts' => $posts);
       }
   }
   ```

   IMO it's a better design but I can't manage to make it works. The routing system stops on the first controller it matches. I'd like to make it act king of cascading style automatically (i.e. if user is staff then go to PostStaffController, otherwise if user is moderator go to PostModeratorController, otherwise go to PostAdminController).
4. Add a listener to kernel.controller in my BlogBundle which will do the same job as number 2 ?

I'm looking for the best designed and the more flexible solution has there's chance that we add more roles in the future.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same situation, have you found a good solution?

Comment: All solutions are good but are bad designed.

If you face the same problem make sure first it's not a bad conception of your application. In my case instead of doing this I made 2 different form type for my entity : i.e. "configuration" and "customization". So admin can access "configuration" and "customization" controllers while staff and moderator can only access "customization".

Not sure if it's clear. Perhaps I should make it a complete answer ?

Comment: You are right, it was a bad design. My solution was to separate different areas of the application in different bundles where I can manage the roles accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: To get a valid answer, I advise you to properly explain your goals. Every solution (even "badly designed") may be acceptable depending on your needs. There are also a lot more solutions like having a custom controller resolver, directly checking permissions in twig. Another solution may also to rephrase your question and understand why it is required to use the same route. Theoretical questions lead to theoretical answer but almost never reflect real world needs.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, You sholdn't fire different controllers for the same route based on roles. It's just different responsibilities. Routes are for select controller, role are for privileges. After a year you will not remember the trick, ie. when you will trying add new role.

Of course the problem of different content for different roles is quite often, so my favorite solutions in this case are:

1. When the controller for different roles is much different, I use different routes with redirect when needed.
2. When the controller is similar but content is different, ie. different database query conditions, I use solution similar to yours 2. but instead forwading, use private/protected methods from the same controller to make the Job. There is one hack - You must check role from top to down, ie. first check ROLE_ADMIN, next ROLE_OPERATOR and last ROLE_STAFF, because when your ROLE_ADMIN inherit from ROLE_STAFF, then block for user catch it.
3. When the difference is just in some blocks of information that should be shown/hide for different roles, I stay with one controller and check role in template to determine which block render or not.

Answer (score 0):

How about an automated version of your second solution? Like:

```
    // Roles ordered from most to least significant (ROLE_ADMIN -> ROLE_MODERATOR -> etc)
    $roles = $myUserProvider->getRoles();
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        // add a check to test, if the function you're calling really exists
        $roleName = ucfirst(strtolower(mb_substr($role, 0, 5)));
        $response = $this->forward(sprintf('AcmeBlogBundle:Post%s:index', $roleName))

        break;
    }

    // Check that $response is not null and do something with it ...
```

Since I don't have your setup I haven't tested the code above.
Btw: what is the difference between the different method to post something?

Comment: Let's say you want to view a post in the admin area : you go to `http://example.org/admin/post/{id}`. Moderators will have a lighter version of the view, whereas admin will see **all** informations about the entity (moderators are clients, admins are developers and people from our company). I don't want to overload my views, form types, controllers etc. with a lot of `if` `else` so that's why I need a dispatcher of this kind. Not sure if that's a good design decision, but that's the only solution I've found at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-controller-event

should do the trick, and make sure to inject security.context service

Answer (score 0):

in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php`

There is an option to replace the `matcher_class` which should be possible in `config.yml`.

If you subclass `UrlMatcher` and overRide `matchRequest` that will take precedence over the Path match (url only).

`matchRequest` takes a parameter $request (Request object)

The Request object should contain the user information provided the security provider listener runs before the router listener and allow you select the route by combining the URL and User Role. The Routes are stored in an array indexed by name so the names will need to be different.

You could possibly use names like `post_index[USER]` `post_index[STAFF]` `post_index[MODERATOR]`

In order to generate the urls with `{{ path('post_index', {...}) }}` you will also need to replace the subclass the `URLGenerator` and inject that into the Router with the `generator_class` option.